# Making a Json-Server work in realtime with angular and heroku

Tags: angular, typescript, json-server

I deploy my json-server to Heroku page, and it`s works fine! I consume my db json in angular, but when I change one value, my app don't show that change if I don't refresh the page.

I want show the result in realtime like firebase show. Someone knows how I can do that?

My server.js of JSON-SERVER:

```
    const jsonServer = require('json-server');
    const server = jsonServer.create();
    const router = jsonServer.router('db.json');
    const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults();
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

    server.use(middlewares);
    server.use(router);

    server.listen(port);
```

This my Angular function Http Request of HttpClient (angular/common):

```
    ....
    export Class ClientesPage {
    clientes$:Observable<any>;
     .....
    getDataById(key){
         this.clientes$ = this.http.get(this.db.API_URL_CLIENTES+'?id='+key).pipe();
    }
```

and I return in HTML with pipe async:

```
   <tr *ngFor="let cliente of clientes$ | async">
            <th>{{cliente?.id}}</th>
            <td>{{cliente?.nome}}</td>
            <td>{{cliente?.cpf}}{{cliente?.cnpj}}</td>
            <td>{{cliente?.telefone1}}</td>
            <td>{{cliente?.endereco}}, {{cliente?.numero}} - 
             {{cliente?.bairro}}</td>
            <td>{{cliente?.regiaoCliente}}</td>
```